# Changing properties gives error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an array of TCube  and need to change the Material.Modulation to tmReplace at runtime I am trying like so.

```
CreateCube[i].Material.Modulation.tmReplace;
```

but get Record, object or class type required.
Any help on how to edit this property?

thanks
glen

Comment: -1 for?  now is not the time to be scared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateCube[i].Material.Modulation := TTextureMode.tmReplace`

In FMX you will often have to call the type of the enumerators or sets, why this is so I do not know, it's just something I learned from my personal experience.

Comment: Scoped enums, more explicit and clearer, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for explaining, had no idea that you can actually do that because I've never encountered it in the VCL.